# UITableViewCell auto layout best practices

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom UITableViewCell called "CustomCell" in which i set up my constraints in init method.
When i subclass "CustomCell", i add new UI elements and try to update the constraints but it all goes wrong.
To make it work right, i create my constraints in `-(void)layoutSubviews` but i am not sure if this is right or not.
I wonder if i am creating my constraints in the right UITableViewCell methods.

Is there any best practice telling in which method we should create or update the layout constraints ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is good for `UITableViewCell` to set the `constraint` on the below `init` method. Because the frame of the `cell` has updated earlier:-

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

Comment: But when i subclass my custom cell and add new UI to the child cell, i realize that the constraints are not set properly and there is some UI layout issues.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the debug window whether it's saying something about ambiguous layout or not. It may have happen that the NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint of your newly added UI elements conflicted with ones you set up manually. If so, try switching them off by yourUIObject.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

But if you have a possibility to create a cell from the Interface Builder it would let set up constraints from there which is a suggested path to follow